# Find the max and min of a list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I need to find the max and min of a list and then add in a new list. This is my code so far:

```
(define alist '(18 39 57 -4 0)

(define (nMax alist)
  (if (null? (cdr alist))
      (car alist)
      (if (> (car alist) (nMax (cdr alist)))
          (car alist)
          (nMax (cdr alist)))))

(define (nMin alist)
  (if (null? (cdr alist))
      (car alist)
      (if (< (car alist) (nMin (cdr alist)))
          (car alist)
          (nMin (cdr alist)))))
```

and now I'm stuck. How can i add `nMin` + `nMax` in a new list? My output should be something like this:

```
'(57 -4)
```

Comment: do you want the two elements in the same list, or the sum of the two elements?

Comment: yes i want them in the same list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define alist '(18 39 57 -4 0))

(define (max-min alist)
  (list (nMax alist)
        (nMin alist)))

(max-min alist)
> '(57 -4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `(cons (nMax alist) (cons (nMin alist) '()))`